# Queue isEmpty and poll incosistency?

Tags: java, collections

Please see the following code segment:

```
private static Queue<Message> m_Queue;

public boolean isQueueEmpty()
{
    if (m_Queue.isEmpty())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}


public WgwConferenceMessage dequeue(){
try{
 if(!isQueueEmpty())
 {
    Message message = m_Queue.poll();

    if (message != null)
    {
        if (!message.getMessage().equals(""))
            Log4jWrapper.writeLog("Retrieved "  + message.getMessage() + " from queue");
        else
            Log4jWrapper.writeLog(LogLevelEnum.ERROR, "<Queue> dequeue", "Message empty");

        return message;
    }
    else
    {
        Log4jWrapper.writeLog(LogLevelEnum.TRACE, "<Queue> dequeue", " Q is empty!");
        return null;
    }
 }
 else
    return null;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    ExceptionHandler.printException(e, "<Queue>", "dequeue");
    return null;
}
}

public void enqueue(Message a_Message) throws Exception
{
    try
    {
        if (m_Queue.offer(a_Message))
            Log4jWrapper.writeLog(LogLevelEnum.TRACE, "<Queue> enqueue", "Pushed "  + a_Message.getMessage() + " to queue");
        else
            throw new Exception("Queue - Could not push message to queue");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ExceptionHandler.printException(e, "Queue", "enqueue");
    }

}
```

My problem is that eventually I get " Q is empty!" log line.
And I can't understand how can it be?

isQueueEmpty() says the Q is not empty, and poll says it is!

Can you advice please?

Thank you.

Comment: two reasons I could think of: 1- adding `null` to your queue, 2- `multi threading` dequeue..

Comment: You are not checking if it is empty and polling atomically - another thread is removing the element first. You don't need the empty check - just use poll.

Comment: @nafas Re your first point [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) "Queue implementations generally do not allow insertion of null elements, although some implementations, such as LinkedList, do not prohibit insertion of null. Even in the implementations that permit it, null should not be inserted into a Queue, as null is also used as a special return value by the poll method to indicate that the queue contains no elements."

Comment: @AndyTurner oh, ur right mate, I always thought like other collections queue allows null elements too.

Comment: @dushkin what implementation of dequeu have you used?

Comment: @nafas What do you exactly mean by implementation? I use the Java regular API of Queue and the dequeue method implementation is described above. Did you mean for something else? Thanks.

Comment: @dushkin `Queue` is an abstract class, by implementation I mean something like this `Queue m_queue=new ArrayDeque();`  where `ArrayDeque` is an implementation of class `Queue`

Comment: @dushkin in your code above, you don't show how m_queue has been initialized

Comment: @nafas Oh! I am sorry... It is  :   m_Queue = new LinkedList<Message>();

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this code is accessed by multiple threads, the reason is that the check for emptiness and the subsequent polling are not done atomically: they are two separate actions. This means that it is possible for a different thread to call `poll` on the queue in between the first thread checking if it is empty and calling `poll` itself; if there happens only to have been one element in the queue, one of these threads is going to get `null` back from the call to `poll`.

Quoting the [Javadoc for Queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html):

> Queue implementations generally do not allow insertion of null elements, although some implementations, such as LinkedList, do not prohibit insertion of null. Even in the implementations that permit it, null should not be inserted into a Queue, as null is also used as a special return value by the poll method to indicate that the queue contains no elements.

This means that you should use the fact that `null` is returned by `poll` as an indication that the queue was empty - you don't need to do the calls separately.

`poll` may be atomic - depending on the implementation of `Queue` you are actually using:

- If you're using a non-synchronized implementation like `LinkedList`, you should be synchronizing it anyway if multiple threads are modifying the list, making `poll` atomic;
- Concurrent implementations like `BlockingQueue` implements `poll` atomically, so you don't need to worry about doing anything explicitly.

TL;DR:

- Remove the `!isQueueEmpty()` check
- Ensure that your `poll` method is atomic either by choosing a concurrent implementation, or by synchronizing mutations of the queue.

Comment: I found a counter to your claim mate: `LinkedList` is a `Deque` implementation and yet allows `null`, `Dequeu<String> queue=new LinkedList<String>(); ` as said by the quote, it `Generally` doesn't allow `null`, so there is still a possibility depending on the implementation.

Comment: Hi Andy. Thank you. There is only one thread who pushes messages to the Q using enqueue() method, and only one thread which reads from it using dequeue method call.   So, I can't currently understand how come they interfere with each other. Also, the Q is a singleton object, although I notice now that its getInstance method is not protected by a synchronized clause... :-(    Another information is that when I print the Q size I get 60000... Can it be some memory issue??

Comment: "Even in the implementations that permit it, null should not be inserted into a Queue, as null is also used as a special return value by the poll method to indicate that the queue contains no elements." If you're calling `poll`, you should not insert null. Just because you can doesn't mean you should.

Comment: @dushkin You haven't made it clear how the `m_Queue` instance is created: are you sure that nothing else has a reference to the same queue? It isn't necessarily just `poll` calls which will cause this, it is anything which removes items from the list (like `remove`, `clear`...).

Comment: @AndyTurner There are definitely only 2 components which use this Q: one is writing to it and one is reading from it. On a normal operation, the Q size does not exceed 100 objects inside it. After few hours - it reaches 60000 all the sudden

Comment: @AndyTurner Andy, I would be grateful if you could guide me how to achieve the second tip you gave me. Thanks.

Comment: @duskin read the Javadoc for LinkedList, it tells you in the preamble.

Answer (score 1):

your initialization of Queue is as follows:

```
m_Queue = new LinkedList<Message>();
```

`LinkedinList` is an implementation of `Queue` which **allows** `null` to be added.

so basically you are adding `null` values into your `m_Queue`

And as @Andy mentioned, such implementation should not be used when using `poll()` method.

There are two ways to avoid that

1. before adding `Message` to `m_Queue` you can check if its  `null` or not
2. `new LinkedList<Message>();` to `new ArrayDequeue<Message>();` where it throws Exception if you are adding null to your Queue

I prefer second one as it makes it as a Queue should really be.

Comment: Thank you for you help. But can you please explain me how can I insert null object following this code? :  Message obj = new Message(sRequest);
myQueue.getInstance().enqueue(obj);    I will add the enqueue code to the main message above.   When I tried to check if new returns null it said it is a "dead code". Meaning it can never happen! Am I correct?

Comment: Also I see that ArrayDequeue is not thread safe... So, would you still recommend it?

Comment: @dushkin well, I don't know the details of your code, all I can do is to suggest things.  why don't you try something mate, log `m_Queue.size()` at the begining of `WgwConferenceMessage` also make `m_Queue` `Volatile`,